# Can't add more item to the array from json_decode function

Tags: php, laravel

Following is my code:

```
$contents=DB::table('content')->select('*')->where([
        ['gate_id', '=', $id],
        ['cat_id', '=', $did],
    ])->get();
    $rcontents=json_decode($contents,true);
    foreach ($rcontents as $content){
        $content['url_img'] = Storage::url($content['img']);
        $content['url_link']= Storage::url($content['link']);
    }
```

The `img` and `link` just only keep the name of file. I use `Storage::url` to get full url to the file. Inside foreach, when I echo `$content['url_img']` or `$content['url_link']`, they have the value which I want. But after this code, the array `$rcontents` doesn't change. Please tell me why and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you decoding `$contents`? It's a collection returned from the query.

Try the following:

```
$contents = DB::table('content')->select('*')->where([
    ['gate_id', '=', $id],
    ['cat_id', '=', $did],
])->get();

$transformed = $contents->transform(function ($content) {
    $content->url_img = Storage::url($content->img);
    $content->url_link = Storage::url($content->link);
    return $content;
});
```

Comment: I decoded it because the error: 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array' happened. I tried your code but this error happened too

Comment: That's because `$contents` is a collection of `stdClass` objects, use the arrow accessors to get/set properties. I've updated my answer, I missed the array indexes in `url(...)`